# Is postgres 9.1.9 supported by ArcGis 10.1 Service Pack 1?

Tags: postgis, arcgis-10.1, postgresql, postgis-2.0

I want to install Postgres and Postgis.

Now we use ArcGis 10.1 So I install Postgres 9.0.5 But there is not exist Postgis for this version. I try install postgis 2.0.3  But I fail(it is only 32 bit application ) http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/pg90/

So I'd like to install postgres 9.1.3 But I find only 9.1.9 version :(

I'd like to install Postgis because we will use geoserver.

Comment: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.1/index.html#//015100000075000000 however using postgis you will need to utilize sql layers to utilize the data. Also using geoserver you are not going to be able to use esri geodatabase to connect in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supported OS/Database versions are subject to ESRI's [Supported Environment Policy](http://support.esri.com/en/content/supportedenvironmentpolicy), which pretty much states "We have a list of OS/Database versions that we have tested and approved.  Other versions might work, but if it breaks, we don't support it."

9.1.9 may work.  Since it isn't that far from 9.1.3, you have a good chance.  However, there could be issues here and there and it might not be perfect.

Comment: Patch releases (third decimal) are pretty much guaranteed to work, since the PgSQL API and behaviour don't change in patch releases. Same is true of PostGIS. So 9.1.9 should work fine.